# Find amount of notifications through the facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How would I be able to find out how many notifications I have through the facebook php api?  For example, how many unread messages + global notifications + unanswered friend requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`summary.unseen_count` in [/me/notifications](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/notifications)

`summary.unread_count` and `summary.total_count` in [/me/friendrequests](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/friendrequests)

I expect a similar `summary.<something>_count` field to exist for messages, but haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

Prompt the user for manage_notifications permission and call [/me/notifications](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/notifications) and count them up. You could also run a FQL query on the [notifications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification/) table but FQL doesn't support count so you would have to loop through all the records to sum them up as well.